# let $f: J \to \mathbb{R}$ . let $x_n < c <y_n$ be such that $(y_n-x_n) \to0$ show that $\lim _ {n \to \infty} \frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}=f'(c)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

let $f: J \to \mathbb{R}$ be differential function . let $x_n < c <y_n$ be such that $(y_n-x_n) \to0$

show that

> $$\lim _ {n \to \infty}  \frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}=f'(c)$$

i am trying to apply Mean value theorem on $f$ on the interval $[y_n,x_n]$.this gives

$$\frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}=f'(\theta_n)$$

Now as $n$ goes to infinity $\theta_n \to c$. but $f'$ is not given to be continuous.if that was given then  we had done.

But how to approach this problem  since $f'$ is not given to be continous . Any Hint.

Comment: Why $\lim_{n\to \infty }f'(\theta _n)=f'(c)$ ? Differentiable doesn't implies $\mathcal C^1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that expression is equivalent to the definition of derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629122/proving-that-expression-is-equivalent-to-the-definition-of-derivative) Or [Limit of a differentiable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817944/limit-of-a-differentiable-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac {f(y_n)-f(x_n)} {y_n-x_n}-f'(c)=\frac {y_n -c} {y_n-x_n} [\frac {f(y_n)-f(c)} {y_n-c}-f'(c)]+\frac {c-x_n} {y_n-x_n} [\frac {f(c)-f(x_n)} {c-x_n}-f'(c)]$. Can you complete the proof now?